# Skype for business channel will be working after 6/30/2019?

Tags: botframework, skype, skype-for-business

I want to do a chatbot for skype for business, but the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview

says: "**This channel will not be supported after 6/30/2019**"

Does this means that my chatbot will stop working in the future or that It will be still working but it will not have support for issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype for Business bots will continue to work, they will just be not be supported. Additionally, you will not be able to create any new SfB connections/channels to your bots. Finally, any bots connected to SfB will stop working after October 31 2019.

Please see here for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0